# What does "what man soever offendeth" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, archaicisms

What does the following sentence mean?

> He shall be punished, what man soever offendeth.

(It is from the Internet site *[The Forest of Rhetoric silva rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/T/tmesis.htm)*.)

I have a feeling that this means "Anyone who offends anyone else shall be punished," but I am not sure.

Comment: It's a showy way of saying _whoever offends_. It's consciously archaic and made difficult to read on purpose, like all religious and pseudoreligious texts.

Comment: Where on the site does that sentence occur?

Answer (score 5):

***Soever*** is now *[archaic and literary](https://www.google.com/search?q=soever&biw=830&bih=732&sxsrf=ALiCzsZOJx4-dJcSfk8OPE71Co5wppKSsg%3A1662545621561&ei=1W4YY933IZCAhbIPjYOEyAo&ved=0ahUKEwidtsiJuYL6AhUQQEEAHY0BAakQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=soever&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCQgAEEMQRhD5ATIICAAQHhAHEAoyBggAEB4QBzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgQIABBDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoLCAAQHhCwAxAIEAo6CAgAEIYDELADSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUJ4OWL0PYIQTaAFwAHgAgAGQAYgB4QGSAQMxLjGYAQCgAQHIAQfAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)* and it means:

> of any or every kind that may be specified —*used after a noun modified especially by **any**, **no**, or **what***
>
> - gives no information soever [(M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soever))

It is used in the KJV Bible:

> - ***What man soever*** there be of the house of Israel...  (Lev. 17:3 KJV)
> - Then ***what prayer*** or ***what supplication soever*** shall be made of any man... hear thou from heaven  . (2 Chr. 6:29-30 KJV)

It is more commonly

> used for emphasis after words such as ***how***, ***what***, ***which***:
>
> - *howsoever, whatsoever, whosoever* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soever))
>    <sub>*(though even more commonly, **so** is dropped: whatever, however, whoever.)*</sub>

Your sentence could be re-written as:

> *Whatsoever* man <sub>*(meaning **whichever, any man that**)*</sub> offendeth shall be punished.

Comment: *So* can be dropped? Not always without rewriting the sentence — "What man ever there be of the House of Israel" isn't a reasonable English sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dropped from "whatsoever" generally, not in the sentence. Will edit.

Comment: Looking at whatsoever, we see an interruption between syllables, [*tmesis*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/T/tmesis.htm): He shall be punished, *what* man *soever* offendeth.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: It would be tmesis if *whatsoever* was the older form — but my understanding is that the history went the other way, originally with separate words *what* and *soever* allowing different possible phrasings, then fossilising into the fixed phrasing *what soever* and hence into a single word?

Comment: whatsoever man is not right. Whatsoever a man say, etc. It is not an adjective.

Comment: [_...distribute the money **in whatsoever proportion** agreed previously_](https://www.google.com/search?q=whatsoever+meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsYqFkbfRfjCze1GGCTzWPPC5drAQQ%3A1662650307777&ei=wwcaY7n7LoKChbIPsqC-OA&oq=whatsoever&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPkBMgQIIxAnMggIABCABBCxAzIKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoFCAAQkQI6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgQIABBDOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QM6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6DQgAEIAEELEDEMkDEAo6CAgAEIAEEMkDOgUIABCSA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWOAQYMsiaABwAXgAgAG4AYgBpQiSAQM3LjOYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz).

Comment: @Lambie It's archaic. As such, it can be used as a determiner.

Comment: It's archaic for whatever, yes. But I am not sure even then, one would find: Whatsoever  man who offends [others] shall be punished sounds terrible **for**: Any man who offends shall be punished. So, I still think it sounds very bad. I think only Shakespeare can get away with it.

Comment: @Lambie Well, it might have not sounded bad when it was in common use... Otherwise I don't see why Oxford Languages would even mention this use.

Comment: I didn't see that specifically.

Comment: There are instances in the KJV Bible. "Whatsoever man there be of the house of Israel..." (Lev. 17:8 KJV)